# how to disabled email verification in flask app builder

Tags: flask-appbuilder

i have a problem with register new user, using FAB form. How i think, the problem that FAB use email verification, how i can disabled it
I tried to disable the flask app builder in the library itself, but I still get an error that the registration failed

Answer (score 0):

You could overwrite the add_registration method in RegisterUserDBView and remove the call to send_email

From https://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_registration.html